# How to downgrade accidentally upgraded @material-ui/core from v3 back to v1?

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

I accidentally upgraded @material-ui/core from v1 to v3 with npm.

Since this mistake my react-admin does not work, given the current version of react-admin uses material-ui/core v1. They will announce the v3+ support in react-admin 3.0, but the release of that version is still too far for me.

How can I downgrade the current 3.9.3 version back to v1?

Comment: Either fix the version in package.json and run `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm i`  or npm uninstall @material-ui/core and then npm install the version you want.

Comment: I could do that in the meantime, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

npm install @material-ui/core@1.5.1

found it.